# Android GCM通知受信時のServiceでSQLiteを効率良く使うには

Tags: android

レシーバーで通知受信時にサービスを立ち上げてステータスバーに通知を出す処理を定義しています。
ただ、実際にステータスバーに通知を出すかどうかは　サービス内で　SQLite　を用いて判断します。

現在は　サービスに一応　static　で　SQLite　を保持しており、
onStartCommand　で　null　だったらデータベースをインスタンス化しております。
また、　onDestroy　にて毎回クローズしています。

とは言え、サービスは毎回終了する度に　onDestroy　がコールされると思うので
実質１通知を処理するのに毎回　データベースを読み込んでいるかと思います。

データベースのレコードはアプリ起動時に毎回最適化しているのでせいぜい平均５０程度と殆ど負荷にはならないかと思いますが、それでも効率が悪いのには変わりありません…
トークアプリのため、通知はたくさん来ます。

SQLiteはネイティブで保持されているとのことで、closeしないことも考えましたが、
やはり、closeしなかった場合はメモリリークが発生しますし…

通知を処理するサービスでSQLiteを使用するにはどのように保持・管理・closeするのがベストなのでしょうか？

Comment: 「効率が悪い」は、何か測定された結果そう判断されたのでしょうか？
それとも、感覚的なものでしょうか？

Comment: 計測はしてないです。効率悪いのは確かだと思いますが、
そうではないような言い方ですので、OS側でキャシュされてたりするということでしょうか？
ちょっと調べてみます。

Comment: いえ、すでにパフォーマンス上での問題が発生していて、SQLiteDatabaseのテーブル最適化なども施した上での質問なのかをはっきりさせたかっただけですー。効率に関しては、「問題となるまで過度な最適化はやらないほうがよい」という原則もありますので。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっと考えてみました。
通知設定がApplicationクラスのライフサイクルに合うなら、そのスコープで設定値をキャッシュすればsqliteを都度参照しなくて済みませんかね？
ただ、キャッシュコントロールが必要ですし過度な最適化に思えます。
変に延命措置をせず、さくっと終了するほうが全体最適ではないかとも思います。。